# Connect via reverse SSH Mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, ssh, localhost, tunnel

This is my first post here, I hope you can help me.

What I'm triying to do, is connect via reverse SSH to a company' remote server.

```
COMPANY $ ssh -R 36060:localhost:22 local@x.x.x.x
```

Then in the local

```
LOCAL $ ssh company@localhost -p 36060
LOCAL $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p root
```

Everything is good, the conection works in the terminal, I can see the tables, no problem.

After all this, in the php archive.

```
<?php
$cnn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','root','user_database',33060);
?>
```

But always send me an error when I try to opened in the browser.

```
Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 45. Packet size=4739923 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php on line 2
Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php on line 2
```

I try to change the config in the "test server", change in LOCAL and COMPANY the max_allowed_packet = 128M in my.cf but nothing works.

If you have any idea, please help :(

**EDIT: Problem solved!**

SERVER $ ssh -fNT -R 33060:localhost:3306 xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.cl

LOCAL $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33060 -u root -p

And works perfecty :D

Answer (score 0):

here is my php script that connects.
Make sure to add your ssh public key to authorized keys on remote server first.

```
shell_exec("ssh -f -L 3307:localhost:3306 myuser@myhost sleep 10 >> logfile");
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername_local;dbname=$dbname_local;port=3307", $username_local, $password_local);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```